# Two STM32F407 Discovery Boards SPI Polling Example From ST

Tags: stm32, spi

I used STM32Cube IDE ST Example to try SPI Polling communication. I followed SPI_FullDuplex_ComPolling reading file instructions. After I pressed reset buttons of 2 boards, I pressed master board user button. The result is according to readme file is " LED5 turns ON when there is an error in transmission/reception process". I have checked on debugging but meaningless datas are appeared on slave side at aRxBuffer( switch(HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&SpiHandle, (uint8_t*)aTxBuffer, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, BUFFERSIZE, 5000)) ). I did not check master side but both of the boards same leds are on.Even if this is vendor SPI example, this could not work properly( I also checked connections and common ground). I could not fix it. Any ideas?

[image: connection from ST readme file]

[image: Master board]

[image: Slave Board]

[image: connections are Master_CLK(PB13)-Slave_CLK(PB13),Master_MISO(PB14)-Slave_MISO(PB14),Master_MOSI(PB15)-Slave_MOSI(PB15),Master_GND-Slave_GND]

Blue board is Master and green board is Slave. I have used from STM32CubeIDE(File->Import->General->Import STM32Cube Example. Below example list, I chose SPI_FullDuplex_ComPolling named example for STM32F407G-DISC1 board. Also I found github link for code [enter link description here](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/tree/master/Projects/STM32F4-Discovery/Examples/SPI/SPI_FullDuplex_ComPolling). According to the link readme file uncomment in main.c "#define MASTER_BOARD" macro for making the board master and comment the macro for making the board slave.

Comment: You need to be more specific what boards you used, how you connected the boards and what code do they run, in order to anyone to start debugging your hardware setup or code. Add links to boards, code, pictures how they are connected etc.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Can you give a connection diagram instead of a photo?

Comment: OK. I added it from readme file of the link that I described in the question.